# What is the key combination for upgrading backup firmware on gigabyte z170-hd3?

Tags: motherboard, uefi, ps2, ps2-keyboard

Recently switched to gigabyte z170-hd3. some Gigabyte cards have a dual firmware feature, so if the main uefi is flashed incorrectly, it will boot from the backup one.

I upgraded the main firmware through the setup menu of the previous one in order to correct microcode security issues.
However, it tends to randomly boot from the backup firmware after power loss, forcing me to rebuild raid arrays *(because of incompatible settings)*.

It is possible to update the backup firmware : it require a PS/2 keyboard and an undocumented key combination. Such combination is different for every chipset *(on my previous Gigabyte motherboard it was Alt+F11)*.

So what is the key combination for upgrading backup firmware on gigabyte z170-hd3 ?

Comment: Have you checked the manual for this motherboard.  I have serious doubts the process to access the backup firmware isn't documented in the manual.

Comment: @Ramhound : It isn’t documented at all. I double checked for the previous one as well as the new one. In fact, the paper manual [is available online](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5485#manual). The previous combination doesn’t work.

Comment: The combination you believe does work is what exactly?

Comment: Within the firmware shell, if you press F9, does it display information on both firmwares?

Comment: @Ramhound : I have no ideas on the combination which works. I don’t remember for F9.

Comment: Confirm the shortcut that I suggested does not work

Comment: @Ramhound : you didn’t suggested any shortcut/combinations.

Comment: I made a suggestion, I asked you to try something which included which keyboard shortcut you should use, 18 hours ago.  What are you talking about?

Comment: @user2284570 Start a support ticket at Gigabyte...http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/technical-support.aspx

Comment: @Moab : If they have a good reason to not document it, they’re unlikely to disclose it.

Comment: I doubt it, documentation is usually done by a third party and usually sucks, Gigabyte support is actually better than most with technical issues.